# Where did the "pew pew" phrase come from?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre

People make silly phrases like:

> Pew! Pew! I shoot you with my space gun.

Where did the "pew pew" phrase come from?

Comment: super related / same question over on el.se https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315488/where-did-pew-pew-come-from

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close, since the "pew pew" sound isn't limited to laser guns, as far as I know. Is it really an SFF-only concept?

Comment: Non-SFF guns go Bang! Bang! don't they?

Comment: ... but really this was probably invented independently millions of times over after the first science fiction TV shows started airing sometime in the middle of the last century.  I doubt there's any way to track down a first instance.

Comment: A possible candidate is Star Wars. Old scifi tends to use different types of sounds for their guns (often written as zap or blam in comic format from what I can tell), but one of the things Star Wars pioneered was its sound effects. Star Wars blasters is a unique sound that is probably best described as "pew.". https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.popularmechanics.com/culture/movies/news/gmp2486/how-6-of-star-wars-iconic-sounds-were-conceived/

Comment: I'd blame [Brian Blessed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103262/who-informed-the-world-that-brian-blessed-was-making-laser-noises-during-the-fil) in the "Flash Gordon (1980)"

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The linked English SE question indicates that the onomataopeia has been used much earlier, since the era of westerns, and that it closely resembles the sound effect used in TV and Movies for silenced weapons (which, of course, is much quieter than actual silenced weapons).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, maybe.  It's all anecdotal, though, I'm inclined to suspect that the answerer is misremembering - there's not a *whole* lot of difference between Pow! Pow! (which seems more likely) and Pew! Pew! after all.

Answer (score 8):

From [KYM](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/pew-pew)

> While the sound effect of laser-beam has been imitated by sci-fi movie fans for decades (most notably in Star Wars films), popular usage of "pew pew" in online conversations began to surge in mid-2005, around the same time when lolcat & lolspeak phenomena started gaining grounds on 4chan.

The earliest definition of the phrase "pew pew" appeared on Urban Dictionary in August 2005:

interj. 1. Used to imitate the sound made by firing a gun; specifically a laser gun (esp. a Stormtrooper rifle).